# Better formatting for comments and Promoting comment to answer

Tags: discussion, comments, answers

I have seen two things that can be improved while answering.

1. Promoting comment to answer
2. Better way to provide code snippets in comment

### Promoting Comment to Answer

Comment usually helps us to get more information on the question and it is really good that way. But sometimes the user might not be sure whether a solution might work or not. So the user cannot add it directly to answer since it might be misleading. In that case the user can add the answer tentatively to comment section, and the person who asked question can decide whether to promote the comment to answer or not.

### Better way to provide code snippets in comments

While providing tentative answer (or possible approaches or any code needs to be written in comment section) it becomes really difficult when the Apex code exceeds more than a line. There are problems with broken formatting and code becomes unreadable. What is the better way to put apex snippets in comment section ?

Comment: What kind of answer are you looking for ? If comment functionality aren't enough, one can answer. Or Chat, little other options.

Comment: Like jsfiddle for html js and css, is there any standard apex fiddle you recommend ?

Comment: There is vffiddle for VF: http://vffiddle.herokuapp.com/

Comment: When my comments are too long, I write an answer, esp when it includes code. I'll state up front I'd have written a comment (esp when I'm also asking questions of the OP), but that it was too long to write as a comment. I've never had anyone complain or downvote me for doing that. I'll add that if you see someone's comments that you think should be posted as "the answer", make a comment urging them to write them up as an answer to the question.